# Android json array to another textview

Tags: java, android, json, android-listview

I have 3 fragment pages app, in first and third fragment i have listviews and in second fragment only a textview(infoz). The code works fine, but i can't add json string to the textview in second fragment i had tried few ways but i didn't make it.
TextView infoz = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.infoz);
this is a textview i want to populate with  string from array, how can i do it?

here is the code

```
  public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

 private ArrayList<FeedItem> feedList;
 private ArrayList<SecondFeedItem> secondfeedList;
 private ListView feedListView;
 private ListView secondfeedListView;





  @Override  
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);


      String url = "";
      new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url);
    return rootView;  

  }


  public void updateList() {


      TextView infoz = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.infoz);





      feedListView= (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
      secondfeedListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.second_list);


      feedListView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), feedList));
      feedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                      Object o = feedListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                      FeedItem newsData = (FeedItem) o;


                      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FeedDetailsActivity.class);
                      intent.putExtra("feed", newsData);
                      startActivity(intent);
              }
      });
      secondfeedListView.setAdapter(new secondCustomListAdapter (getActivity(), secondfeedList));
      secondfeedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                      Object o = secondfeedListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                      secondFeedItem secondData = (secondFeedItem) o;


                      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), secondFeedDetailsActivity.class);
                      intent.putExtra("secondfeed", secondData);
                      startActivity(intent);
              }
      });
       }


         public class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
              if (null != feedList) {
                      updateList();
              }
              if (null != badfeedList) {
                  updateList();
          }
      }

      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
              String url = params[0];

              // getting JSON string from URL
              JSONObject json = getJSONFromUrl(url);

              //parsing json data
              parseJson(json);
              return null;
      }
     }


       public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
      InputStream is = null;
      JSONObject jObj = null;
      String json = null;

      // Making HTTP request
      try {
              // defaultHttpClient
              DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
              HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
              is = httpEntity.getContent();

              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                              is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      sb.append(line + "\n");
              }
              is.close();
              json = sb.toString();
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
      }

      try {
              jObj = new JSONObject(json);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
              Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
      }

      // return JSON String
      return jObj;

         }

      public void parseJson(JSONObject json) {
      try {

              // parsing json object
              if (json.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                      JSONArray posts = json.getJSONArray("posts");


                      String inffoz;

                      feedList = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

                      for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                              JSONObject post = (JSONObject) posts.getJSONObject(i);
                              FeedItem item = new FeedItem();

                              item.setTitle(post.getString("title"));
                              item.setDate(post.getString("description"));
                              item.setId(post.getString("id"));
                              item.setUrl(post.getString("url"));
                              item.setContent(post.getString("description"));
                              item.setsecondtitle(post.getString("description"));

                              JSONArray attachments = post.getJSONArray("attachments");
                              item.setsecondtitle(post.getString("secondtitle"));
                              if (null != attachments && attachments.length() > 0) {
                                      JSONObject attachment = attachments.getJSONObject(0);
                                      if (attachment != null)
                                              item.setAttachmentUrl(attachment.getString("url"));
                              }

                              feedList.add(item); 

                      }

                      } 






              if (json.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                  JSONArray posts = json.getJSONArray("posts");

                      secondfeedList = new ArrayList<secondFeedItem>();

                      for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                              JSONObject post = (JSONObject) posts.getJSONObject(i);
                              secondFeedItem item = new secondFeedItem();
                              item.setTitle(post.getString("title"));
                              item.setDate(post.getString("description"));
                              item.setId(post.getString("id"));
                              item.setUrl(post.getString("url"));
                              item.setContent(post.getString("description"));


                              JSONArray attachments = post.getJSONArray("attachments");

                              if (null != attachments && attachments.length() > 0) {
                                      JSONObject attachment = attachments.getJSONObject(0);
                                      if (attachment != null)
                                              item.setAttachmentUrl(attachment.getString("url"));
                              }

                              secondfeedList.add(item); 

                      }

              }




      } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }




   }
```

json

```
 {
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 10,
  "posts": [
   {
      "id": 2398,
      "type": "post",
      "slug": "",
      "url": "",
      "status": "publish",
      "title": "bla",
      "description": "bla",
      "date": "2013-06-11 ",
      "content": "dadadadaddaadad",
      "secondbadtitle": "blaaaaaaa",
      "attachments": [
         {
            "id": 2342,
            "url": "",
            "slug": "",
            "title": "",
            "description": "",
            "content": "dadadadaddaadad", 
            "caption": "ssss",
            "parent": 2398,
            "mime_type": "image/jpg",
            "images": []
         }

     ],
     "comment_count": 3
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to set the text of the textview with just any string?

Comment: yes, i did test that with infoz.settext(string); String string = dsds;

Comment: Alright, just wanted to make sure that worked. Did you decompile the JSON array into strings? edit: successfully*

Comment: Well all json objects go to feedList = new ArrayList<FeedItem>(); and FeedItem class implements Serializable

Comment: Will you please give me your JSON format?

Comment: I agree with Blue, can we please see the JSON string you read in?

Comment: i added to the question, everything works fine, but i can't take a string from json for textview

Comment: Where do you try to set text to the TextView?

Comment: in the public void UpdateList, there i defined a textview but i can't settext to him

Answer (score 0):

TRy       this.......

```
 List list=new ArrayList();
        JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(str_response_starter);

        JSONArray json_array_item_id = jObject.getJSONArray("itemid");
        System.out.println("json array item id"+json_array_item_id);

        JSONArray json_array_item_name = jObject.getJSONArray("itemname");
        System.out.println("json array item name"+json_array_item_name);


        JSONArray json_array_item_type = jObject.getJSONArray("type");
        System.out.println("json array item type"+json_array_item_type);

        JSONArray json_array_item_cost = jObject.getJSONArray("cost");
        System.out.println("json array item cost"+json_array_item_cost);
```

It will be better for us if you give format of JSON. By the use of collection class it is so easy task. If you got any issue then please let me know

Comment: i added json to the question :)

Comment: First is JSONArray. Then first store json String in JSONArray now you can use count , status ,comment_count by get jsonarray . Now Post is JSONObject , access by getJSONArray the data of post id. If there any issue please let me know

Comment: but how can i add it to textview?  infoz.setText(json_array_item_id); don't work

Comment: from there parse it out into strings, or try .setText(""+json_array_item_id);

Comment: Ok .Where are you using .setText? try suggestion of Samuel. If it work then Upvote .If not again ping me

Comment: Dont work, please read question again, i have gived the little better explanation.